# Embedding a 2D linear transformation into 3D

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, linear-algebra

From [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Common_rotations), I know that the matrix

[image]

will rotate a 2D vector `v` by 90 degrees clockwise when I take the matrix-vector product `Mv`.

Now I want to apply that same rotation to a 3D vector, keeping 1 chosen dimension fixed. For the sake of exmaple, lets say we keep `y` fixed. (I'm assuming we're in the standard Cartesian coordinate system with dimensions x, y, z.)

To do that, I can construct sort of a mix `M'` of the 3D identity matrix and my rotation matrix M, where I take M, add the extra dimension `y` by adding zeros to `M`, and then set `M'[1,1] = 1` so `M'` is the identity in the `y` dimension.

[image]

**Question:** Let's get to my question :)
I have code for computing `M'` in Python, shown below. It works by computing `M'` from `M` similarly to the way I described above, but this feels rather ad-hoc and tedious.
Can I express this more elegantly in terms of standard linear algebra operations instead? I'm looking for concise, beautiful code.

**Details:** In my code, a "move" is any 90 degree rotation (clockwise or counterclockwise) of some "slice" (hyperplane) pointed to by a standard unit vector or its opposite. I encode a move as a pair `(v, d)`, where `v` is the vector (ranging over all `v` in `{-1, 0, 1}^3` with 1-norm equal to 1), and d is the "direction" (1 for clockwise, -1 for counterclockwise).

```
def rotation_matrix(move):
    [v, direction] = move
    fixed_dim = 0 if v[0] else 1 if v[1] else 2
    assert v[fixed_dim] != 0
    M = np.zeros([3, 3])
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if i == fixed_dim or j == fixed_dim:
                M[i][j] = 1 if i == j else 0
            elif i == j:
                M[i][j] = 0
            else:
                M[i][j] = direction if i > j else -direction
    return M
```

**What I have tried so far:** If I take the outer product `np.outer(v, v)` I get a 3-by-3 matrix that is the identity for my fixed dimension. and `0` everywhere else. Now I just need a way to combine that with the 2D rotation matrix somehow...

**EDIT:** After iterating a bit with ChatGPT4, I ended up with the following code. It is more concise and more efficient (on my machine), though it still doesn't feel "canonical" in the way I was hoping for.

```
def rotation_matrix(move):
    [v, direction] = move
    # The rotational axis is the dimension into which `v` is pointing.
    fixed_dim = [i for i in range(3) if v[i]][0]
    # The rotation takes place in the other two dimensions.
    [r1, r2] = [i for i in range(3) if i != fixed_dim]

    M = np.zeros([3, 3])
    M[fixed_dim, fixed_dim] = 1
    # The 90 degree rotation matrix [[0, 1], [-1,0]], adjusted by direction.
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Common_rotations
    M[r1, r2], M[r2, r1] = direction, -direction
    return M
```